# Changing the username for a Subversion commit over svn+ssh

Tags: svn, ssh

I've run into an issue with our Subversion configuration here: I've checked out a project over svn+ssh on the local Linux system. So svn info reports something along the lines of:

```
URL: svn+ssh://MYUSERNAME@server/svn/project/trunk/
```

Now my co-worker is unable to update the checked out working copy (It's on a live server) because the command line parameter --username doesn't work with svn+ssh.

How can I temporarily change or remove the username from the repository URL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use "svn switch --relocate" to change the repository server URL to just the address without his username.

**Edit**: The syntax is pretty simple; sorry I hadn't explained it in my initial answer.  Basically, you just cd into the working copy, and run:

```
svn switch --relocate svn+ssh://MYUSERNAME@server/ svn+ssh://server/
```

That should take the username of the user running that command.  I'm also fairly certain that you can also specify the new username in that URL (though am not in front of a unix box right now, so I can't test this).

Does that command not do what you intended when you ran it from the command line?

For more information, see the [red bean chapter on svn switch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch04s05.html).

Comment: Thank you, that's probably it. I am still trying to figure out the correct syntax though.

Comment: Just for reference: The correct syntax is using the --relocate switch.