# How to change the username used by Subversion on svn+ssh

Tags: unix, svn

I have the following problem. I got a fresh svn repository, and when I try to do 'svn ci' the username that it asks for is my current machine's username instead of the username created for subversion. Passign the --username parameter is also ignored.
I've tried a few potential solutions including this http://highlevelbits.com/2007/04/svn-over-ssh-prompts-for-wrong-username.html, but it doesn't seem to be working with subversion 1.7. I had seen that on a past issue from 2007.

Anyone has a suggestion ?

Comment: Do you authenticate via password or via client-certificate?

Comment: I've just noticed that the solution to my issue is already on this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581485/changing-the-username-for-a-subversion-commit-over-svnssh.
I leave it to the moderators to decide whether they want to close it as duplicate.

Comment: @PeterRader I authenticate via password, like in the attached issue.

Comment: Actually the better solution for this issue is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703034/changing-username-in-svnssh-uri-on-the-fly-in-working-copy?rq=1